# wiki iphone project

Tags: iphone, wikipedia-api

I'm currently working on an iPhone project where i want to present to the user spesific terms from wikipedia. I'm facing tow difficulties right now:
1. I want the specific content to work offline.
2. I want to show the relevant pictures as well.

I need to find the most efficient way to do it, can someone advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the content online and cache them in the app DB. If necessary you could prepolutate the db directly in you app. That way some terms would already be available.

Comment: yeah but what is the best way of doing that ?

Comment: Best way? Just download it and store it to whatever format you want.

Comment: These tutorials should introduce you to using the DB of an iphone http://mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/